# How to add "rank" column to mysql table depending on the score with different categories?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My table:

```
user | score | category
-----------------------
 1   |  20   |    1
 2   |  30   |    1
 4   |  30   |    1
 1   |  20   |    2
 2   |  30   |    2
 4   |  30   |    3
```

Expected result:

```
user | score | category | rank
------------------------------
 1   |  20   |     1    |  3
 2   |  30   |     1    |  1
 4   |  30   |     1    |  1
 1   |  20   |     2    |  2
 2   |  30   |     2    |  1
 4   |  30   |     3    |  1
```

I need to make a permanent change to the table (not only select this value) so that I could select users like:

```
SELECT `user`, `rank`, `score` FROM `user` WHERE `category` = 2
```

My real table is 200k+ rows and has much more columns. It has to be fast.

Comment: Why is the same score(20) with 2 different ranks?

Comment: @Mihai Because it's another category. This is the point.

Comment: Don't store this. Just calculate on-the-fly

Comment: What happens when another row is added?  Do you need to update 200k+ rows every time?

Comment: @Craft what is rank represent actually

Comment: @Tom This never happens. It's a read-only table.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you know how to do it fast?

Comment: I do :-) Join me after the break...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider an alternative (which you may find to be faster) to a correlated subquery approach which involves using session variables

```
SET @n := 0, @r := 0, @c := NULL, @s := NULL;
UPDATE users u JOIN
(
  SELECT user, score, category,
         @n := IF(@c = category, @n + 1, 1) rnum,
         @r := IF(@c = category, IF(@s = score, @r, @n), @n) rank,
         @c := category, @s := score
    FROM users
   ORDER BY category, score DESC
) r
    ON u.category = r.category
   AND u.user = r.user
   AND u.score = r.score
   SET u.rank = r.rank;
```

Outcome:

```
| USER | SCORE | CATEGORY | RANK |
|------|-------|----------|------|
|    2 |    30 |        1 |    1 |
|    4 |    30 |        1 |    1 |
|    1 |    20 |        1 |    3 |
|    2 |    30 |        2 |    1 |
|    1 |    20 |        2 |    2 |
|    4 |    30 |        3 |    1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26463/1)** demo

Comment: I have never used session variables before and I don't know how to adapt your solutino to my needs. Because except category I have also gender and season and I guess this changes a thing.

Comment: *I have never used session variables before...* There is always something to learn :)

Comment: *I don't know how to adapt your solutino to my needs* That why you either include all details in your question or ask a follow-up question... But anyway I'm glad you found what you was looking for.

Comment: Ok, I have understood your solution and added more conditions and it works! It does the magic in about 5 minutes on about 200k rows. This is exactly what I was asking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query to get the rank:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from MyTable2 t2
        where t2.category = t.category and
              t2.score > t.score
      ) as rank
from MyTable t;
```

You can put this into an update, by joining again back to the original table, assuming the `user, category` is unique:

```
update MyTable join
       (select t.*,
               (select count(*) + 1
                from MyTable2 t2
                where t2.category = t.category and
                      t2.score > t.score
               ) as rank
        from MyTable t
       ) toupdate
       on MyTable.user = toupdate.user and Mytable.category = toupdate.category
    set Mytable.rank = toupdate.rank;
```

Comment: The select is great and very simple but the update took me a couple of minutes and I restarted the db. But the select is so good that I don't need an update anymore. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A minor variant on peterm's solution. And I don't advocate UPDATE unless you're sure that this table is read only...

```
SELECT category
     , user
     , score
     , @pcat := @ccat
     , @pscore := @cscore
     , @ccat := category
     , @cscore := score
     , @rank := IF(@pcat = @ccat,IF(@pscore = @cscore, @rank, @rank+1),@rank:=1) rank
  FROM my_table
  JOIN (SELECT @ccat :=null,@pcat := null,@cscore := null, @pscore := null, @rank := 0) sel1
 ORDER 
    BY category,score DESC;
```

or something like that. I think this will perform significantly faster than Gordon's elegant solution.